# JNI Invocation API Create Event Listener for Swing

Tags: java-native-interface, invocation-api

I am trying to create a JButton inside C++ with Invocation API without Java any code. But I cannot add the action listener to this button.

This is my code, when I compile and run it only a warning appears and nothing happens after clicking button.
[0.145s][warning][jni,resolve] Re-registering of platform native method: java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V from code in a different classloader

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
#include <thread>


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL actionPerformedNative(JNIEnv *envlocal, jobject obj) {
    // Implementation of the native method
    std::cout << "Hello from native method!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Initialize the JVM
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=.";
    vmArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
    vmArgs.nOptions = 1;
    vmArgs.options = options;
    vmArgs.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vmArgs);
    jclass jFrameClass = env->FindClass("javax/swing/JFrame");
    jobject frame = env->NewObject(jFrameClass, env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"), env->NewStringUTF("JVM Integration"));
    jclass jButtonClass = env->FindClass("javax/swing/JButton");
    jobject button = env->NewObject(jButtonClass, env->GetMethodID(jButtonClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"), env->NewStringUTF("Click me!"));
    jmethodID addMethod = env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "add", "(Ljava/awt/Component;)Ljava/awt/Component;");
    env->CallObjectMethod(frame, addMethod, button);
    jmethodID setDefaultCloseOperationMethod = env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "setDefaultCloseOperation", "(I)V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(frame, setDefaultCloseOperationMethod, 3);  // JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    jmethodID setSizeMethod = env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "setSize", "(II)V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(frame, setSizeMethod, 300, 200);
    jmethodID setLocationRelativeToMethod = env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "setLocationRelativeTo", "(Ljava/awt/Component;)V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(frame, setLocationRelativeToMethod, nullptr);
    jmethodID setVisibleMethod = env->GetMethodID(jFrameClass, "setVisible", "(Z)V");
    env->CallObjectMethod(frame, setVisibleMethod, JNI_TRUE);

    jclass actionListenerClass = env->FindClass("java/awt/event/ActionListener");

    JNINativeMethod actionPerformedNativeMethod = {
        "actionPerformed",        // Method name
        "(Ljava/awt/event/ActionEvent;)V",  // Method signature
        (void*)&actionPerformedNative      // Function pointer to the native implementation
    };
    int result = env->RegisterNatives(actionListenerClass, &actionPerformedNativeMethod, 1);
    jobject actionListener = env->NewObject(actionListenerClass, env->GetMethodID(actionListenerClass, "<init>", "()V"));

    if (result == 0) {
        std::cout << "Native method registered successfully." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cerr << "Error registering native method. Error code: " << result << std::endl;
    }

    jmethodID addActionListenerMethod = env->GetMethodID(jButtonClass, "addActionListener", "(Ljava/awt/event/ActionListener;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(button, addActionListenerMethod, actionListener);

    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this concept possible with JNI Invocation API without writing any Java code?

Comment: No. You need *some* custom Java class to attach your native methods to. The best you can do is a call to `DefineClass` with the bytecode of such a Java class, but then you might as well ship the class file or a jar containing said class file and load that as normal.